# PhpStorm take undefined variable error for passes variables to view

Tags: laravel, intellij-idea, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm using last version of PhpStorm v2019.2. In this version take `Undefined Variable` for all passed variable to view from controller

```
@foreach( $specifications as $specification )
     @php
         $type_spec = $specification->types->where('id',$property->type_id);
     @endphp
@endforeach
```

or other error picture in PhpStorm, we passed `$property` from controller and code work correctly

[image: Or other error]

Comment: It is not very clear where you are having issues. Do you have any errors? Is you loop not looping properly? Are you passing specifications properly from the controller? Give us the code where you return this view.

Comment: We pass all of them form controller, work on host and local correctly this error just in PhpStorm

Comment: IDE does not know what variables come into what view. If you need them to be "known", use PHPDoc `@var` and declare (so IDE knows that such variable indeed exists and what type that is/what methods can be called). IDE does not provide any special support for Laravel framework (it's done by 3rd party plugin), but IDE provides plugin for Blade files.

Comment: in v2017 or v2016 not exist this problems, and in this version this variables without error in `{{  }}` and just take error in `@php`

Comment: IDE treats content inside `@php` as if it would be normal valid `<?php ... ?>` block. The stuff inside `{{ }}` can be anything, so it's not checked that much (as variables may be coming from anywhere).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `/* @var $your-variable */` to the same `@php` block

```
 @php
     /* @var $property */
     $property->load("rejects")
 @endphp
```

OR

On top of your `fileName.blade.php`

```
 <?php /* @var \App\Models\YourClassName $property */ ?>
```

Tested with v2019.1.3 + Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 2):

Try this in top of your view:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @var object $property
 */
?>
```